# Turning off fuzzy search conditionally in Super Search

Tags: solspace, search, supersearch

Is it possible to conditionally turn off fuzzy search results in Super Search via search syntax and/or setting the fuzzy_distance parameter to 0?

We have a case where we want to apply fuzzy search to all except for certain saved URLs (or certain search results).

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot turn off the fuzzy feature per set. It is currently a global feature.

Comment: Got it. Then, are the two parameter values: 

fuzzy_distance="0" fuzzy_weighting="no"

The closest we can get to "turning off" the fuzzy search?

Comment: Yes, in theory.